# Pop ups VS Collapse blocks for adding new info

Tags: forms, popup, collapsible-panels

when i want to add a new field for an existing entity, to add a new field it is required to submit a 3 fields form.
is it better to open the form in a pop up and disable the background or is it also ok (or even better?) to use the option of collapse form, meaning when a user clicks on add the fields will be shown below on the current page?

i do like better the idea of collapse than the pop up, since i find pop ups really annoying

what do you think is better?

Comment: Pop ups disconnects users from the flow, one should avoid them for the type of action you are trying to perform. Adding a controls dynamically is definitely an option but it depends on how rest of your form/screen is designed.

Comment: i have a brand page which includes two independent blocks of information:
1. contact info
2. tech specs
since the blocks are not related i want to let the user the ability to edit/add new info or specs/ delete for each block of the page separately.
so what i did now is when a user want to add more info the form is collapse under the current info we have on that section. 
the form for both blocks are short- 3 fields.

Comment: I am not saying popup should be used here, infact I am inclined towards collapsible structure. But as you have mentioned popups are really annoying, I am taking this opportunity to direct you towards  http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/40172/is-pop-up-always-bad. This might help you take informed decision.

Answer (score 1):

**Collapse Blocks**

- Because you are adding onto an existing entity, it makes more sense to keep the user in the context of that entity, rather than popping up out of context.
- Multiple additions in a row would lead to a "ping pong" experience. The user hits the add button and Ping! You're in an overlay. Submit the form and Pong! Back to the main screen. Hit the add again and Ping! And Pong!
- You are creating a non-continuous workflow. If this addition is one step in a longer workflow, you shouldn't use a popup.

**Pop-up**

- A pop-up will command a user's focus. If this is part of a large page, an inline collapsing block may be lost if the user starts scrolling.

**It Depends**

- Keep this consistent with the rest of your site. Is there already an established mode of interaction?
- Try usability testing or A/B testing both solutions if you can